# Get the column/property name which throws DataIntegrityViolationException in Spring Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm using Java 7, Spring 4 and Hibernate 4. I'm working on handling exceptions in each layer for user input.

Starting near the DB, I would like to know if there is a way to get the column name (other than splitting the String message from MySQL exception) or the property name from org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException. In order to know exactly which property/column is wrong (as I have the same constraint on different property/column).

```
try {
     fooRepository.save(foo)
} catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    if(e.getRootCause() instanceof MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getRootCause().getMessage());
    }

    if(e.getRootCause() instanceof MysqlDataTruncation) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getRootCause().getMessage());
    }
}
```

Right now, I'm only able to get the String message, e.g. "Data too long for column 'FOO_BAR' " and yes I can get the column name but I thought it may exist a clean method to do it!

```
rootMsg.substring(rootMsg.indexOf("\'") + 1, rootMsg.lastIndexOf("\'"));
```

Let me know if you need more explanations and thanks for any help!